Unable to write avatar image to file system on server using .NET 9.0
I have an API to load a user avatar up onto an images folder in my .NET 9.0 app. The code works perfectly on my dev machine (rolls eyes). The deployment mode is self-contained. The target runtime is win-x64.
The directory does exist on the server and it has "all" privileges.
This is simplified code without the file checking etc:
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAvatar(IFormFile file)
{
    string directoryPath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "public", "images"); 
    var filePath = Path.Combine(directoryPath , $"{userId}{fileExt}");

  // Save the file to the path
  try
  {
      using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
      {
          await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
      }
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
  {
      Log.LogException(ex, Log.ErrorLevel.HIGH);
      return StatusCode(500, $"Unauthorized access error: {ex.Message}");
  }
  catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
  {
      Log.LogException(ex, Log.ErrorLevel.HIGH);
      return StatusCode(500, $"Directory not found error: {ex.Message}");
  }
  catch (IOException ex) // This is where it catches
  {
      Log.LogException(ex, Log.ErrorLevel.HIGH);
      return StatusCode(500, $"IO error: {ex.Message}");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Log.LogException(ex, Log.ErrorLevel.HIGH);
      return StatusCode(500, $"Internal server error on file write: {ex.Message}");
  }

I am getting the error:

IO error: Could not find file 'D:\sitename\public\images\GUID.png' "

where GUID is the userId of the user uploading the avatar and the server file path is correct.
Originally I was using /wwwroot/images, but the server admin had assigned "all" privileges to the folder and I was still getting the error

IO error: Could not find file


the file path (which was correct). I decided to try a dedicated folder and assign a PhysicalFileProvider path for the avatars in case there was some arcane reason why I couldn't write to the wwwroot directory structure.

In program.cs I have:
var directoryPath = Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "public", "images");
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(directoryPath),
    RequestPath = "/img"
});

Which seems to work if I copy a file up using FTP.
The error

Could not find file

seems apropos of nothing when I am writing the file.
I am assuming the app is running under IIS default user as the admin hasn't set it any other way.

Hi @davaus, after checking the issue carefully, it seems not the permission issue. You can verify it by double-click the project_name.exe file for test.

According to my experience, If we want to eliminate the problem of permission issue (Physical Machine), maybe we need a machine which is out of your organization. Some security policy may cause some issue, we can use process monitor to check what happened.

You might try a quick check for the directory before copying the file... I use this bit of code:  string imagefolderName = "images" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
string ImageFileRootPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, imagefolderName);
if (!Directory.Exists(ImageFileRootPath))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory(ImageFileRootPath);
}  (This writes uploaded files to a folder that only code has access to...  I serve the file from an enpoint to avoid deep-links and then set <img src to the endpoint with uid....)  If you use wwwroot folder, users can bypass authentication.

Thanks guys for your suggestions. browsermator - I am showing you simplified code. I actually have directory existance checking in the real code, and i can see through FTP that the directory does exist anyway.
